# Why did some stigmatized theophoric names survive in English?

Tags: etymology, history, names

The synopsis is: we have the long-standing popularity of the name "Isabelle" and context that much of the English speaking world has been influenced by Christianity for centuries. It appears that "Isabelle" and "Jezebel" have a (at least a partial) common origin:

> Isabella is a feminine given name, which is the Latinised form of
> Hebrew Elisheba (whence also Elizabeth) or the Latinised form of
> Jezebel (אִיזֶבֶל‎, ʾĪzével, ʾĪzeḇel).
>
> — [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isabella_(given_name))

With this in mind, it is noteworthy that the differences between the two names go beyond the God/Baal dimension. Etymologies concerning Isabelle not only use "God" in place of baal, but also sound more pleasant: "Oath to God", "God is plenty", ect. Compare this to the theonym of Jezebel which has negative-sounding sobriquets: "devotee of Baal", "vestal virgin of Baal", "concubine of Baal".

One could argue that "Baal" can also just mean lord in Hebrew. However, given how ubiquitous the story of Jezebel is, it would be hard to imagine how a Christian society would look past the literary connotation of Baal as in the Canaanite deity, of whom Jezebel was the infamous priestess.

### Question

Why were some theophoric names, like "Isabelle" tolerated as holdovers despite a transparent paper trail that traces the name to its Canaanite pantheon roots, while other Biblical names, such as "Judas" appear to have far less sympathy?

**Note:** Just academic interest into the matter, nothing personal against anyone named "Isabelle"!

Comment: Isn't it also plausible that the name came from "Elisheba"?

Comment: What I find strange is that _Delilah_ is apparently a popular name in the USA.

Comment: There are a few first names with with less good associations, like *Lilith*, *Jezebel*, *Delilah*, but none of them are very common in terms of lists of the most popular names. I guess some such names could be used in literature/media for symbolic reasons, and then be used in real life by people familiar with the media but unaware of the Biblical associations. (And powerful women even if less than good can become icons.)

Comment: "Isabelle" is a synonym for "Elizabeth", not "Jezebel". Specifically, the French synonym, later borrowed into English. You must remember that Christianity was - and is - practiced by speakers of many languages, and each language transliterated the Biblical names in its own way. Sometimes in multiple, often highly divergent ways. James and Jacob are synonyms, as are Jesus and Joshua

Comment: @KateBunting I'd speculate all those american Delilah's were named after the woman in the Tom Jones song rather than the one in the Bible.... but I could be wrong 

Comment: @FraserOrr: Chicken and egg. Who was the Delilah that Tom Jones sang about named after?

Comment: Quite apart from etymology, many – probably most – English speakers know that _belle_ and _bella_ means ‘beautiful’ in Romance languages, and Isabel(le/la) contains that at the end. Contemporary associations trump etymology in virtually all cases.

Comment: (1.) I don't know quite what you mean by "christian society". English-speaking society has been, on the whole, very un-Christian. (2.) The Canaanite "roots" are actually more of a "branch": although the paper-trail may not be so clear beyond (earlier than) them, there was certainly some sort of trail there. Do you know who the Canaanites borrowed "Baal" from?

Comment: @Flater Who was the Delilah in the Bible named after?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I don't think your etymology is correct. The name of the Canaanite god was Baal, with a glottal stop represented with the Hebrew letter ayin בַּעַל (Ba-al) which I don't think corresponds with the last syllable of אִיזֶבֶל *Isabel*.

Note *Isabel* is the most common spelling in English.

According to [etymology online](https://www.etymonline.com/word/Isabel) Isabel is in fact a variant spelling of Elizabeth אֱלִישֶׁבַע Elisheva, who was the wife of Aaron the high priest.

> fem. proper name, a form of Elizabeth that seems to have developed in
> Provence.

So, what I think we have here is a false friend. The Isabel of אִיזֶבֶל is not the source of the modern English word at all. In fact the modern name (and presumably its various romance language equivalents) is a variant of Elizabeth, which comes form a entirely different source.

Elizabeth's Hebrew roots convey the idea of God (El) is my oath (sheva), which seems to be quite a good association with a perfectly well regarded woman in the Bible.

As an aside, more to do with Hebrew than English, that word "oath" *sheva* (or sometimes *sheba*, depending on how you transliterate one of the letters) means, an oath or a covenant. Beersheba, for example, is the well of oath. However, it also means "seven" as in the number seven, which is probably why in the Bible the number seven is often associated with the divine or heavenly things.

Comment: The name of the Canaanite god was Baal Hadad. His father was El. El was also the father of Yahweh.

Comment: @Greybeard Do you have a source for "El was also the father of Yahweh?"  That's some theology that's new to me...better yet, is there a family tree somewhere showing all three or more?  I'm wondering if Baal Zebub is another brother.

Comment: Behind the Name (which I find to be a generally good source for etymologies of names) agrees that [Isabel derived from Elizabeth](https://www.behindthename.com/name/isabel).

Comment: Zevel (V and B same letter) means *dung* in Hebrew. Eee-zevel (Without-dung, No-shit) is not a flattering name. Not sure that Baal, her deity, played a role in her name...or whether the author of Kings was dumping on her.

Comment: Beelzebub (Baalzevuv), Lord of the Flies, is unrelated. There, *baal* (perhaps the devil) just means any lord/owner, not the Baal worshipped as an idol.

Comment: @CristobolPolychronopolis Deu:32:8-9 "the most High" is El (the creator god) and by implication Yahweh is his son. In Ex:32, Yahweh is described as being in a cloud and Aaron builds the golden calf - the clouds and the calf are symbols of Baal Hadad - the god that had brought them out of Egypt... The Ugaritic Texts show that Yahwists adapting verses for Baal H. The references to cedars are to Baal H. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadad

Comment: @Greybeard - Surely Yahweh _is_ God, who by definition is of all time and didn't need a father? But this is straying into theology and away from the English language.

Comment: @KateBunting The definition is definitely not "from all time". Yahweh worship did not start until about 16th c. BC. At that time, he seems to have been Canaanite /Levantine god and related to earlier gods. The two separate creation myths that are combined in Genesis makes the distinction between El (the creator god) and Yahweh, in a rather confused manner.

Comment: Why did they use ayin for a glottal stop in the spelling of "Baal" in Hebrew? That's what aleph is. On the other hand, the "-al" part was probly cognate with Arabic and Hebrew god names.